# Firebase OAuth's callback URL does not include the project ID

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to use Twitter authentication with Firebase Auth.

As usual I created a project in the firebase console and added a web app, but the project ID is not included in the callback URL, and cannot work with twitter app.

How can fix this?

Thank you for hearing my poor English.

[empty callback url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wka4r.png)

[process which caused the problem](https://youtu.be/T_e-byFYHJg)

Comment: Please can you include abit more context to your problem, code snippets and/or commands you used

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I added the process which caused the problem. Please check the URL.